# How to run a select query based on data from another select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with two tables groups and members. The columns from these tables are below.

Groups table:
group_id,group_name

Members table:
member_id,group_id,status

I have an app that needs to display a list of groups along with the groups members. What is the most efficient way to say `SELECT * from groups` then for each group/row returned do another select on the members table to query the members (for example `SELECT * FROM members WHERE group_id=X`).

Comment: Do you know how to use `JOIN`? If not, good place to start.

Comment: I suppose the join gets the data back but then I have a separate row for each member. In my application I want to show each group then the member of each group separately. Ideally in the app I'd pass through an array of groups then groups.member would be the members. I'm not sure who I would get this type of output from a join? Thanks for the fast response as well!

Comment: You'll have to decide what to do in your application code and what to do in your query. Sometimes MySQL is not the place you want to do certain data transformation operations.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
   g.group_id,
   g.group_name,
   m.member_id,
   m.status

from groups g 
     inner join members m on g.group_id = m.group_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both `members` and `groups`  have a column named `group_id`, you can use `join` to fetch the results you want:

```
select m.*
from members as m
     inner join groups as g on m.group_id = g.group_id
where group_id = X
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM groups g
LEFT JOIN members m
ON g.group_id = m.group_id
```

This would return all groups and their members.

You can introduce variables, so for example

```
SET @groups = (SELECT TOP 1 group_id FROM groups)
```

and add it to your query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM groups g
LEFT JOIN members m
ON g.group_id = m.group_id
WHERE g.group_id = @groups
```

Comment: `top`? Isn't that for SQL Server? I think you mean `select group_id from groups limit 1)`